# Polymer.dart propertyNameChanged method in a custom library isn't working

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

This is my polymer.dart class.

```
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';

/**
 * A Polymer x-changer element.
 */
@CustomTag('x-changer')

class XChanger extends PolymerElement {

  @published String prop;

  propChanged() {
    print("prop changed!");
  }

  /// Constructor used to create instance of XChanger.
  XChanger.created() : super.created() {
  }


}
```

This is my project structure:

- example

  - chat_example
  - lib
  - web
- lib

  - x-changer.dart
  - x-changer.html
- test

When I add x-changer.dart & x-changer.html in my example folder it works. It is exactly the same code, am I missing something that is important for a polymer element library?

EDIT:
This is the library pubspec

```
name: some_elements
description: >
  The polymer elements for ...
version: 0.0.1
author: Joris Hermans
#homepage: https://www.example.com
dependencies:
  polymer: '>=0.15.4 <0.16.0'
dev_dependencies:
  unittest: any
```

Comment: How does the import of the element in the entry page look like? If the examples are in the same package you need also to add the entry_point to the transformer config.

Comment: This is the link to the project https://github.com/ExperimentalForce/force_elements

Comment: Never refer the `lib` directory in imports. Always use package urls (Dart code and HTML) like shown in my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I updated my code, but it doesn't work, it still don't print 'prop changed!'

Comment: I'll check it out and try it myself...

Comment: Thanks! Probably something very small ... I am overseeing.

Comment: I had to change the polymer dependency in the example project to make it compatible with the force_elements package (`polymer: '>=0.15.4 <0.17.0'`) but otherwise it just worked. I set a breakpoint at `print("prop changed!");` and it was hit. I suggest to not put one project into another. This is not a well tested path.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74485/discussion-between-joris-hermans-and-gunter-zochbauer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the polymer transformer in the library (without entry_points).

You shouldn't import like `You shouldn't import like``

It should look more like

You shouldn't import like `<link rel="import" href="packages/chat_example/force/force_client_element.html">`

You might need one or more additional `../` prefixes, depending on where the importing file resides (this is never necessary in Dart package:xxx imports.

`<link rel="import" href="../packages/chat_example/force/force_client_element.html">`

See https://www.dartlang.org/polymer/app-directories.html for more details.